# 301 redirect all except robots.txt file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

In my htaccess I have redirect all pages from my domain to main page.

I would like just to exclude from this redirect `robots.txt` file and url like: `http://www.example.com/?123` to `http://www.example.com/`. Is it possible?

I have tried following .htaccess rules:

```
RewriteRule .+ http://www.example.com [r=301,nc,l]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples please try following .htaccess rules file. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/. [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s(?:\S*)/robots\.txt/?\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com [QSD,R=301,L]
```